# Ubuntu budgie 20.04 freezes for a few seconds on boot, then works normally

Tags: 20.04

Whenever I boot up Ubuntu, it starts running and then freezes for about 30 seconds or so, then resumes working correctly. I have it installed on an external ssd. After I can resume control of my computer, dmesg -T shows this, although I'm not sure if its related. After this initial freeze it works perfectly for the rest of the time my computer is on, until the next reboot.

```
[Wed Jan  6 22:46:24 2021] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#19 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD OUT 

[Wed Jan  6 22:46:24 2021] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#19 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 51 3c 28 00 00 68 00

[Wed Jan  6 22:46:24 2021] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#8 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN
 
[Wed Jan  6 22:46:24 2021] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 12 1b 1b f0 00 00 30 00

[Wed Jan  6 22:46:26 2021] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#16 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN
 
[Wed Jan  6 22:46:26 2021] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 03 10 08 80 00 00 08 00

[Wed Jan  6 22:46:26 2021] scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start

[Wed Jan  6 22:46:26 2021] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd

[Wed Jan  6 22:46:26 2021] scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

Anyone have any advice on what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled Ubuntu budgie on an new internal ssd that I bought, works flawlessly now, no freezing whatsoever. I can assume that the external ssd I was using was to blame, or possibly just a corrupt installation of Ubuntu.